# Create ARReferenceImage programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am downloading images from the database and want to use them as ARReferenceImage, instead of manually adding them to Xcode asset folder.

**Code**

```
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mike")
    let cgImage = image.cgImage

    guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.init(cgImage, orientation: .portrait, physicalWidth: 100) else {
        fatalError("Failed to load image")
    }
```

**Error**

Ambiguous reference to member 'init(_:orientation:physicalWidth:)'

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but are you actually expecting the image to be 100 meters wide?

Comment: haha not really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGImagePropertyOrientation not support `.portrait` Please use below support:

```
public enum CGImagePropertyOrientation : UInt32 {


    case up // 0th row at top,    0th column on left   - default orientation

    case upMirrored // 0th row at top,    0th column on right  - horizontal flip

    case down // 0th row at bottom, 0th column on right  - 180 deg rotation

    case downMirrored // 0th row at bottom, 0th column on left   - vertical flip

    case leftMirrored // 0th row on left,   0th column at top

    case right // 0th row on right,  0th column at top    - 90 deg CW

    case rightMirrored // 0th row on right,  0th column on bottom

    case left // 0th row on left,   0th column at bottom - 90 deg CCW
}
```

Your code:

```
 let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage(cgImage!, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.up, physicalWidth: 100)
```

**Or**

```
let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.init(cgImage!, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.up, physicalWidth: 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

`CGImagePropertyOrientation` doesn't have a member named `.portrait`.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimagepropertyorientation) it has `.up`, `.upMirrored`, `.down`, `.downMirrored`, `.leftMirrored`, `.right`, `.rightMirrored`, `.left`. If you use one of these in your initializer it should work.

For example:

```
let referenceImage = ARReferenceImage(cgImage, orientation: .up, physicalWidth: 100)
```

Comment: Note that this only applies if your image data actually is in `up` orientation. Otherwise you need to get the `UIImage`’s orientation and convert the `UIImageOrientation` value to a `CGImagePropertyOrientation` value — e.g. if `UIImage` says `portrait`, you say `up`.

Comment: @rickster That is correct, I only put `.up` as an example but it should be checked before usage unless you know for sure what orientation it will be.